# How do I verify a user over the telephone?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

We have users -they can call us on the telephone. How do we validate that the users are who they say they are?

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Check personal information such as date of birth: DOB can be guessed from Facebook and Linkedin + there are data-protection issues around storing DOB
2. Check the telephone number of the user: I was told that it's easy for an attacker to forward calls to a device that they control
3. Create a database of security questions and answers: we would have to create and maintain a database

Is there a standard robust way of doing this?

Comment: great artists steal: call a dr office and note the authentication routine they use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on publicly know information is problematic. Storing personal security questions+answers is unlikely to scale well if many others adopt the same approach.

If you want to authenticate someone who is using **your** service, ask them questions about their association with you. Examples include:

1. Give all users an account number, transaction number for the issue, etc.
2. Ask about past transactions / orders (and make sure this is something that they can access easily)

Calling them back on a given telephone number is also a useful approach, and adds defense-in-depth. However, you then need to think about mutual authentication-- how can you ensure that the user trusts the call. If done right, this can further boost the security of your system.

Make sure you use some form of rate limiting and track when authentication attempts are made. Make sure these attempts are communicated back to the user "out-of-band".

Answer (score 2):

The premise of identification without them being physically hinges on the ability to verify information that could not be easily known to the public. Typically, they have to verify information like the last four of the social security number in the US, in some instances employees are given an employee ID and a passphrase that is randomly assigned to that username specifically for this circumstance. Additionally, sometimes they are required to identify things like Account Numbers, Addresses on file, etc.